# Using data out of observable subscribe for return

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, ionic-framework, ionic3

struggling since few days on below code.

the subscribe is executing after the result is accessed.(check comments)

how to wait till subscribe finishes so that the result variable can be read and returned please help

```
place.ts
import { HttpClient } from '@angular/common/http';
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { String } from 'typescript-string-operations';
import {Observable} from 'rxjs' 
import  { Response } from '@angular/http';
import 'rxjs/add/operator/map'

@Injectable()
export class PlacesProvider {
  apiKey='AIzaSyBuMEEL-0XZX1jSi5yO1GJcuDECegwSD6o';
  baseUrl='https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/{0}/json?{1}&key='+this.apiKey;

  constructor(public http: HttpClient) {
  }

nearBy(lat:any,long:any,radius:any):any
{
  var nearbySearchParameters='location='+lat+','+long+'&radius='+radius+'&type=school';
  var apiType='place/nearbysearch';
  var apiUrl=String.Format( this.baseUrl,apiType,nearbySearchParameters);
  console.log("request=>"+apiUrl);
  this.http.get(apiUrl)
  .map(resp=>resp);

}

nearByAddress(address:string,radius:any):any
{
  let nearbysearchResults:Observable<any>;
  let result:any;
  this.getGeoCode(address)
  .subscribe(nbp=>{
             console.log(nbp);//results are here
             result=nbp.results[0];   
          });
          console.log(result); // result is undefined 
          return this.nearBy(result.geometry.location.lat,result.geometry.location.lng,radius); // i want to use this return as observable with pipe on UI which is saying undefined
}

 getGeoCode(address:string):any
{
 var geoCodingPagerameters='address='+address;
  var apiType='geocode';
  var apiUrl=String.Format( this.baseUrl,apiType,geoCodingPagerameters);
  console.log("request=>"+apiUrl);
  var results:any;
  return this.http.get(apiUrl,{ responseType: 'json' })
         .map(resp=>resp);
}

}
```

Home.ts

```
getNearbyLcs(): any {
    this.nearbyLcs= this.placesProvider.nearByAddress(this.address.place,'500');
  }
```

home.html

```
<ion-title *ngFor="let lc of (nearbyLcs|async) ">{{lc.name}}</ion-title>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can use switchMap and subscribe only when you need the result

```
private nearBy(lat: any, long: any, radius: any): Observable<any> {
            const nearbySearchParameters = 'location=' + lat + ',' + long + '&radius=' + radius + '&type=school';
            const apiType = 'place/nearbysearch';
            const apiUrl = String.Format(this.baseUrl, apiType, nearbySearchParameters);

            console.log("request=>" + apiUrl);

            return this.http.get(apiUrl).map(resp => resp);
        }

    public nearByAddress(address: string, radius: any): Observable<any> {
        return this.getGeoCode(address)
                   .switchMap(nbp => {
                      let result = nbp.results[0];
                      return this.nearBy(result.geometry.location.lat, 
                               result.geometry.location.lng, radius);
            });
    }

    getNearbyLcs(): any {
                this.placesProvider.nearByAddress(this.address.place,'500')
                    .do(console.log)
                    .subscribe((res) => this.nearbyLcs = res);

      }
```

Answer (score 0):

Okay, here is another approach, using `flatMap()`. Please, give it a try.

```
private nearBy(lat: any, long: any, radius: any): Observable<any> {
    const nearbySearchParameters = 'location=' + lat + ',' + long + '&radius=' + radius + '&type=school';
    const apiType = 'place/nearbysearch';
    const apiUrl = String.Format(this.baseUrl, apiType, nearbySearchParameters);

    console.log("request=>" + apiUrl);

    return this.http.get(apiUrl).map(resp => resp);
}

public nearByAddress(address: string, radius: any): Observable<any> {
    let result: any;

    return this.getGeoCode(address)
        .map(nbp => {
            console.log(nbp);//results are here
            result = nbp.results[0];
        }).flatMap(res => {
            return this.nearBy(result.geometry.location.lat, result.geometry.location.lng, radius);
        }).subscribe(data => console.log(data));

}
```

Comment: just tried this but the results are not even logging with console.log(results)